# Para usar la pila interna en recursividad que debe retornar la función?

Tags: c++, recursión

Estoy realizando un problema de recursividad que da la suma de los dígitos de un numero (ej 234 =9)y una parte de las indicaciones señala que  se debe hacer procesamiento recursivo de formula de cada problema (hacer uso de la pila interna) y que no se vale  " pasar como parámetro a la función recursiva resultados parciales de acumuladores que la formula necesite"

No entendí eso ultimo y acabe el programa pero me parece que algo estoy haciendo mal porque no uso el return al regresar mas que en el ultimo caso y me aparece la advertencia de "*wreturn-type: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]*", ¿Por qué y cómo lo arreglo?

Aquí esta el código (que por cierto si funciona pero no creo que el funcionamiento sea el correcto) :

```
int suma(int a)
{ 
    //Caso base? que "a" sea 0, a almacena el numero para la siguiente llamada quitando el ultimo digito 
    //declaracion de variables y cosas previas a condicion
    int aux=0,residuo=0;

    if ( a != 0 )
    {
     
       residuo=a%10;
       a=a/10;
       aux=aux+residuo+suma(a); 
    }
    else
    {
        aux= a;
        return aux;
    }
}
```

Comment: efectivamente, el `return aux` no debería estar dentro del `else` sino fuera del condicional. La función va a retornar algo, aunque no pongas `return`. Lo que está sucediendo es que cuando no hay `return`, se devolverá lo que se encuentre en el registro correspondiente ... tu estás teniendo la suerte de que lo que se encuentra en ese registro es justamente el valor de `aux`. Si la función retornase cualquier otro valor, tu programa dejaría de funcionar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> me aparece la advertencia de "*wreturn-type: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]*", ¿Por qué y cómo lo arreglo?

El error es claro y conciso, tal vez no lo entiendas por estar en inglés, te lo traduzco:

> "*tipo-de-retorno: el control alcanza el final de una función no-void*"

Te está advirtiendo que en una función no `void` (es decir, una función que se espera que devuelva algo) se llega al final sin haber devuelto nada. Y efectivamente es así, cuando `a` no es cero (`0`) la función `suma` no devuelve nada:

```
int suma(int a)
{ 
    int aux=0,residuo=0;

    if ( a != 0 )
    {
// Si entramos aquí...
        residuo=a%10;
        a=a/10;
        aux=aux+residuo+suma(a); 
// llegamos hasta aquí y el 'else' no se ejecuta.
    }
    else
    {
        aux= a;
        return aux;
    }
// Llegando al final de la función sin devolver nada.
}
```

Para evitar ese error todos los caminos que pueda seguir la función deben desembocar en un retorno de valor, por ejemplo:

```
int suma(int valor)
{
    if (valor)
        return (valor % 10) + suma(valor / 10);

    return 0;
}
```